# Error 542 - N appears in the dimension of a variable

Tags: arrays, fortran

```
program factorial
implicit none
integer:: n1
real:: fact = 1.0
integer:: n = n1
integer, dimension(1:n):: x
integer:: i
print *, "Enter a number:"
read *, n1
x(1) = n1
do i=1,n1-1
  x(i+1) = n1-i
  fact = fact*x(i)
end do
print *, fact
end program factorial
```

I have written a code for calculating factorial of a number. I am asking the user to put in an integer 'n1', after which it will create an array variable containing n1 compartments. I am unsuccessful in compiling this. I keep getting the following error!

> factorial.F95(6) : error 542 - N appears in the dimension of a variable, yet is not a dummy argument, a variable available through USE or CONTAINS association, a COMMON variable, a PARAMETER, or a PURE FUNCTION
>    Compilation failed.

How can I fix this? I want the array dimension to be equal to the input number. For example, say I want to calculate 5! (5 factorial), I want the x array to be of 5 (row or column) element length. Somehow, I am unable to do that!

Comment: You don't need an array to calculate factorials.

Comment: note there is no reason to use the array `x` here at all, just do `fact=fact*(n1-i+1)`

Answer (score 1):

The constant `n1` needs to be a compile time constant to be used as a static array dimension

```
program factorial
implicit none
integer, parameter:: n1
integer, dimension(1:n1):: x
```

or you need to use allocatable arrays.

Answer (score 0):

As Vladimir suggested, you have to allocate the array:

```
integer, dimension(:), allocatable :: x
integer :: alloc_stat

print *, "Enter a number:"
read *, n1

ALLOCATE( x(1:n1), STAT=alloc_stat )
IF ( alloc_stat .ne. 0 ) THEN
    WRITE(ERROR_UNIT,*) "Array allocation failed."
    ERROR_STOP alloc_stat
ENDIF
```

(I always check the status of my ALLOCATE statements.  It's not whether you are paranoid or not, it's whether you're paranoid **enough**.)

Comment: I am not saying he needs to allocate the array. You can advice that, but I did not say that.  Abd do not write to 6, it is not guaranteed to be the same as * which the OP uses. It is an unneeded magic number https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)#Unnamed_numerical_constants

Comment: here you may as well static dimension `x(85)` You cant calculate a factorial this way at single precision for larger n anyway.

Comment: @VladimirF I always write my error messages to 6.  (Started with Fortran 66, so I'm still a bit stuck in my ways.)  But you are correct that I should not use 6.  I should use `ERROR_UNIT`.  I will fix my answer accordingly.  Thanks.

Comment: But 6 is not even the error output, it is the standard output in most compilers. The * one. Error_unit is typically 0.

Comment: this is kind of getting off in the weeds, but if you want to use `ERROR_UNIT` or `OUTPUT_UNIT` you need `USE ISO_FORTRAN_ENV` as well.     `write(*,*)` is just fine for a simple example IMO.